# Rails on heroku ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: SSL error: cert already in hash table

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I build `Rails3.2` apps with devise and deployed on heroku.
Does anyone have any solution to solve against following issue?
After sign-in operation, following error is occured and respond `http status 500`.

```
2012-10-14T05:29:08+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE   
 (lower(username) = '***' OR lower(email) = '***') LIMIT 1):
2012-10-14T05:29:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:23:in    
 find_for_database_authentication'
2012-10-14T05:29:08+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-10-14T05:29:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: SSL
 error: cert already in hash table
2012-10-14T05:29:08+00:00 app[web.1]:    
 app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `create'
2012-10-14T05:29:08+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-10-14T05:29:08+00:00 heroku[router]: POST agile-cliffs-   
 6123.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=45ms status=500 
 bytes=643
```

Actually, devise registration functions works fine, but sign-in doesn't work.
This issue is only occured on production.

Answer (score 1):

Editing my non-answer from before: We finally found the core of the problem!

We're using the ruby-openid-apps-discovery gem because we have our app integrated with GApps Marketplace. We're using the gem in its raw form, but if you're using OmniAuth and have the google_apps strategy enabled, you're also using it.

It comes down to line 255 of http://code.google.com/p/ruby-openid-apps-discovery/source/browse/trunk/lib/gapps_openid.rb

The loading of the additional CA certificates (add_file) pollutes OpenSSL and the current Postgres SSL connection is corrupted

```
@@store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
@@store.set_default_paths
@@store.add_file(ca_bundle_path)
```

Your only option is to reconnect to Postgres or monkey patch the store() method and remove the call to add_file. The Heroku dyno already has the stock CA certs and that's enough to do the GApps OpenID discovery, apparently.

FYI, I tried doing a clean room repro of this problem with a blank Rails app with just OmniAuth and the google_apps strategy enabled and was unable to repro .. so perhaps it's the combination of this ruby-openid-apps-discovery gem and one other component in our app that's also playing OpenSSL games to contribute to the problem .. I'd file a bug against this gem but the project looks mostly dead and since I can't repro the problem cleanly, I can't say with 100% certainty that its at fault.

Comment: I had similar issue in my Rails app using ruby-openid-apps-discovery gem. In my case the problem was caused by updated bcrypt-ruby gem, version 3.1.2. I resolved it by downgrading bcrypt-ruby to 3.0.1